# Logging currently executing line of code in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, v8

Is there a way to run a node script and log each executing line of code without modifying the script code?

For example, given a simple script.js file with this content:

```js
const a = 1
const b = 2
a + b
```

I would like to be able to log something like

```
path: "script.js" line: 1
path: "script.js" line: 2
path: "script.js" line: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The closest is probably V8's `--trace` flag, which logs all function entries and returns. It works in Node too (where it will show a bunch of insight into Node's internals).